# Geometric Cauchy Problem

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry

I'm attending a course in Symplectic Mechanics and I have some problems in understanding something written in my lecture notes.

We are in the following setting: let $Q$ be a manifold (of dimension $n$) and let $\Sigma$ be a connected submanifold of dimension $n-1$ in $Q$. We denote with 
$$j\colon\Sigma\hookrightarrow Q$$
the inclusion mapping.
Suppose we are given a smooth function on $\Sigma$, $\sigma\colon\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}$ (which is understood to represent the initial or boundary data for our Cauchy problem - see below), and a Hamiltionian function $H\colon T^{*}Q\to \mathbb{R}$ (so $H$ is smooth too). We denote by $\pi_{Q}\colon T^{*}Q\to Q$ and by $\tau_{Q}\colon TQ\to Q$ the projections onto the base manifold (the map of the bundles).

Now start troubles: my professor defines 
$$L_{(\Sigma,\ \sigma)}:=\{p\in T^{*}Q:\ (d\sigma)(v)= p((Tj)(v)),\ \forall v\in T\Sigma,\ \pi_{Q}(p)=\tau_{Q}(v)\}.\qquad \left(\triangle\right)$$
Here $d\sigma\colon \Sigma\to T^{*}\Sigma$ associates to $q\in Q$ the map $d_{q}\sigma\colon T_{q}Q\to \mathbb{R}(\simeq T_{\sigma (q)}\mathbb{R})$ and $Tj\colon T\Sigma\to TQ$ is the map between the tangent bundles induced by the inclusion. (I also think that, in $\left(\triangle\right)$, $\pi_{Q}(p)=\tau_{Q}(v)$ is a slight abuse of notation for $\pi_{Q}(p)=\tau_{Q}((Tj)(v))$).

For my way of reasoning, the definition in $\left(\triangle\right)$ was not clear enough, so I asked my professor about it and, for what I was able to understand, $\left(\triangle\right)$ should be suitably written as:

$$L_{(\Sigma,\ \sigma)}:=\{(q,\ p)\in T^{*}Q:\ \forall (\lambda,\ v)(\ ((\lambda,\ v)\in T\Sigma\ \land q=\lambda )\implies (d\sigma)(v)= p((Tj)(v))\ )\}.$$
Well, if this is the right way of understanding this definition, if I'm not missing something, we get that if $q\in Q \setminus \Sigma$, then *every* $(q,p)\in T^{*}Q$ should belong to $L_{(\Sigma,\ \sigma)}$ because the hypotheses in the implication defining $L_{(\Sigma,\ \sigma)}$ is always false.

Now, there is another definition in my lecture notes. If $e\in \mathbb{R}$ is a regular value for $H$, a *solution of the Geometric Cauchy Problem (for the Hamilton-Jacobi system associated to H)* is a Lagrangian submanifold $\Lambda\subseteq H^{-1}(\{e\})$ such that

$$j^{*}(\Lambda\cap L_{(\Sigma,\ \sigma)})=(d\sigma)(\Sigma).\qquad (\square)$$

I basically can not understand what the lhs of this equality should be: I know pullbacks of vector fields and of differential forms, but I don't know what it means to do a pullback of a submanifold of the cotangent bundle. I can't give any concrete meaning to the lhs of $(\square)$, even trying to force it with some abuse of notations.

So my questions are:

1. Is my rephrasing of $(\triangle)$ meaningful?
2. What's the meaning of the lhs in $(\square)$ and of the equality itself?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Just to be sure there is no confusion, the definition of a differential k-form for me is [this one.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Intrinsic_definitions)

Comment: I believe the in the first formula (△) it should read $π_Q(p)=τ_Q(v)$. And in the second (□), $j^∗(Λ∩L_{(Σ, σ)})=(dσ)(Σ)$, so that $Λ$ satisfies the boundary conditions.

Comment: @LutzL Yes, that's right, I corrected the typos, but still I don't know answers to my questions 1. and 2. In particular I still don't understand the (mathematical) meaning of (the lhs of) $(\square)$...

Comment: L contains the tangent hyperplanes (encoded by co-vectors, minus a little scaling) that are compatible with the tangent planes of the initial data σ. Or said in other terms, σ has slopes in the directions of Σ. Any continuation of σ to Q needs to have the same slopes in direction of Σ. Now Λ as a submanifold of the cotangential bundle is not nessecarily the differential of a continuation of σ, i.e., Λ is rarely fully integrable. But the second condition demands that Λ is at least a continuation of dσ.

Comment: @LutzL I'm sorry man and I don't want to seem rude, but I was not able to understand anything of what you said (certainly it's my fault, but basically I can't figure out the (mathematical) meaning of the words you used: what does it mean "little scaling", "hyperplanes compatible with tangent planes", "slopes in the direction of $\Sigma$" etc.?). Maybe I'm a little bit old fashioned but what I'm looking for is something like: $j^{\ast}(\Lambda\cap L)=\{r\in T^{\ast}\Sigma:\ P(r)\}$, where $P$ is some property (including possibly other variables) which can be expressed in the language of ZF(C).

Comment: In points $q\in Σ$, $L$ only contains elements of the fiber $T^*_qQ$ that are continuations as linear functionals of $(dσ)_q$ from the tangent space $T_qΣ$ to the larger tangent space $T_qQ$. The second condition tells you that $Λ$ should contain in every fiber of $T_q^*Q$, $q\in Σ$ at least one such continuation. That $j^∗(Λ∩L)\subseteq(dσ)(Σ)$ is automatic from the construction. $P(r)\iff r=(q,p)\in j^*Λ\land p=(dσ)_q$.